# Ext js MVC 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: php, extjs, yii

I am developing a website in yii framework where I am am using ext js 4 mvc structure.
I am trying to use ext js 4 with yii framework.
I am using MVC in ext js 4 where i get forbidden message.

During execution of this application I get below message
`GET http://localhost/helloext/protected/controller/Users.js?_dc=1350173045981 403` (Forbidden)

Below is my application structure:-

```
helloext-
--extjs // contins ext js 4 sdk
--protected
  --controllers
    --Users.js
--app.js
--index.html
```

**Code:-**
1)index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Account Manager</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-debug.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

2)app.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'helloext',
    appFolder : 'protected',

    controllers:['Users'],

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: '',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: '<b>Balaee<b>',
                    html : 'List of users will go here'
                }
           ]
        });
    }
});
```

3)
protected
--Users.js

```
Ext.define('helloext.protected.controllers.Users',
        {
            //extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
        extend: 'Ext.protected.Controllers',

        init: function() {
            this.control({
                'viewport > panel': {
                    render: this.onPanelRendered
                }
            });
        },

        onPanelRendered: function() {
            console.log('The panel was rendered');
        }
        }
);
```

How I integrate yii framework with ext js 4 mvc?

Comment: have you checked http://www.ext4yii.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You said, "***Below is my application structure***" and your application structure seems something different. anyway...

`protected` folder is strictly restricted to the browser. Check the **.htaccess** (*it is hidden in windows*) file inside your `protected` folder and it contains `deny from all`. That's the reason why you get `403 Forbidden`

1) Move `Users.js` outside of `protected` folder.

2) Remove .htaccess file (but it's a **Security Risk** )

2) or, use the Yii's assetManager.

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/2032-assets/
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to redesign your Extjs Application to be compatible with Yii framework's design.
In order to do so, I'd recomend the following structure:

```
/yiiApp

      /protected

          /assets

              /yourExtjsApp
```

You will also need to use Yii CAssetManager to publish your assets (aka. your ExtjsApp) so that they are worldwide accessible:

`$assetUrl = Yii::app()->getAssetManager()->publish('application.assets', false, -1, false );`

(you can do this wherever you want, I'd recommend views/layout/main.php or even protected/config/main.php so that you can access the assetUrl at a later time)

Finally in your protected/views/layout/main.php or protected/views/index.php (whichever you prefer), you can create your Extjs Application as follows:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'yourExtjsApp',
    appFolder: '<?php echo assetUrl; ?>',
    ....
```